# Cannot Resize React Barcode to the defined width and height

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have come across a problem in resizing the React Barcode Image, my preferred size for all barcodes is width 200px and height 100px. As I know, the width of the barcode will be expanded when the length value is increased. Below are my current code:

```
import BarCode from 'react-barcode';
 <BarCode format="CODE128" className="ss" style={{height:"200px"}} displayValue={false} width={1.3} height={50} value="dasdasndaslndl2"/>
 <BarCode format="CODE128" displayValue={false} width={1.3} height={50} value="2937197921"/>
 <BarCode format="CODE128" displayValue={false} width={1.3} height={50} value="quoe232871217"/>
```

I am using this package to generate barCode: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-barcode
I am expecting all the generated Barcode has a consistent design with whereby same height and width.

I have implemented other solution and it provide me the defined width but the height of barCode has been resized to become more smaller than before.

```
  const Wrap = styled.div`
  svg {
    width: 150px;
    path {
      fill: red;
    }
  }
`;
<wrap>
<BarCode format="CODE128" className="ss" style={{height:"200px"}} displayValue={false} width={1.3} height={50} value="dasdasndaslndl2"/>
</wrap>
```

Thanks.

Comment: it depends on if `BarCode` resizes it for you, because it'll overwrite your style. If you identify the exact svg element, just do `height: 200px !important;`

Comment: Tested does not work ..

Comment: Leave a ticket in BarCode github then, there's no way if his style overwrites your style. Maybe play with the `width` or see if he has a ratio setting you can play. Actually you should see the overriden line  that everytime it changes the height. If you see that line, that basically confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in width, height, format, and displayValue as properties of the 'options' prop, like so:

`<BarCode className="ss" value="dasdasndaslndl2" options={{width: .7, height:50, format: 'CODE128', displayValue: false}}/>`

For the **width** property use a number between 0 and 1 (or more) and for **height** use a number between 1 and 100 (or more).

In the react-jsbarcode [Readme](https://github.com/iamchathu/react-jsbarcode) you can see at the very bottom that the 'format' property is passed into the Barcode component via the 'options' prop.

Answer (score -1):

If you dig into the docs for `react-barcode` it's just a thin wrapper on top of [`jsbarcode`](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode). Review the [react-barcode source](https://github.com/kciter/react-barcode/blob/master/src/react-barcode.js), it's super simple. The syntax of the original package accepts:

1. Destination (SVG or Canvas HTML element ID as `string` (ie- `#my-svg-id`);
2. Numbers under the barcode as `string` (ie, `12879532`);
3. Options as `object` (ie `{ width: 200px }`)

The react package turns all of the object key/value pairs into props. So where you've gone wrong in your attempt is that you're **passing the height  as a style prop**, whereas the height/width need to be passed as a regular prop:

```
<BarCode 
  value="dasdasndaslndl2"
  format="CODE128" 
  className="ss" 
  displayValue={false} 
  width='200px' 
  height='100px'
/>
```

Comment: Hi Serraisays, I have attempted by setting the pixel inside "height" and it still remains to adjust the dimension of the barcode by using ratio aspect.

Comment: @MiracleHades set up a codepen or something so we can have a look.